# Post data with special character

Tags: php, html, summernote

I have problem when post data in php that contain special character:

> String: ? < > ' - \" `´& % ‰ € ® 2011

that always display

> String: ? < > ' - " `Â´& % â€° â‚¬ Â® 2011

i changed form attribute be:

```
<form  id="frmBlog"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and also i change html with meta attribute:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

but the result still same. anyone can help to fix this problem. thank you

my simple code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_POST['content'];
    exit;
}

$content = "String: ? < > ' - \" ´& % ‰ € ® 2011";
?>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="content" rows="20"><?=
        $content
        ?></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

output:

```
String: ? < > ' - " Â´& % â€° â‚¬ Â® 2011
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your browser is actually following the charset instruction?

Comment: Have you also checked the encoding of your source files?

Comment: Your source .php file must be also saved with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: The encoding of the source file should make no difference. The output you're seeing is your browser/client attempting to decode a UTF-8 encoded string as ISO-8859-1 (or other single-byte character set).

Comment: when display in form i try to: $['content'] "String: ? < > ' - \" `´& % ‰ € ® 2011";    when post data echo $_POST['content']; this display value: String: ? < > ' - " `Ã‚Â´& % Ã¢Â€Â° Ã¢Â‚Â¬ Ã‚Â® 2011

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2):

If your string goes through a database, that could be the problem. Try to change database encoding options. (This worked for me once)

Otherwise, try to use `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` and see if you still have the problem. And if you still do, then the problem is probably in your form, or the way it is submitted (in my opinion).

**EDIT:**

Your problem was that when you echo the content, the charset is not yet defined, and that causes the problem. You should echo after the `<head>` , like this:

```
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['content'];
        exit;
    }

    $content = "String: ? < > ' - \" ´& % ‰ € ® 2011";
    ?>


    <form method="post" action="post.php">
        <textarea name="content" rows="20"><?php
            echo $content;
        ?></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried and not work

Comment: are you sure you don't have some spaces or hidden characters in your string?

Comment: i  just modify my post with my simple code

Comment: so basically the problem was that this was a test. In a production environment, your code would have probably worked ;)

Comment: @hermans If you have any control over the server, it's far better to set the character set with an HTTP header than with a `<meta>` tag.

Comment: ok problem solved, i just change my database charset: //SET CHARSET 'utf8   thank for your help